# Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for modplug

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I try to download an application in Apple Store Connect I get an error "Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for modplug". Who knows how to fix this?

[image]

I tried the following methods:

1. Removed unnecessary files from Copy Bundle Resources.
2. In plist added:

```
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>iPhoneOS</string>
    </array>
```

3. I was looking for .dSYM files in the project. I didn’t find anything.

What else can you do? I've been trying to fix this for two days now.

os: macOS 10.13.6

xcode: Version 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: I assume `modplug` is some kind of a dynamic framework in your build setup. Does it have deployment target set to any iOS version?

Comment: @Kamil.S I’ve been developing the application for the second month and uploaded it to the AppStore Connect a week ago. Everything was fine, but yesterday this error occurred.
I don't know anything about modplug.

Comment: are you using any 3rd party frameworks?

Comment: @Kamil.S  'Firebase/Core' and 'Firebase/AdMob'. But they were before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. First I deleted the ~ / Library / Developer / Xcode / DerivedData / ModuleCache directory. Then I created the project again. And only then I was able to download the application in the Apple Store Connect.